# Why is it that , to newline is working but newline to , is not working sed?

Tags: sed, newlines

I have got a text file with a list of first names, and I am trying to replace newline with **,**.

Here is the command I am using

```
sed 's/\
/,/g' file
```

while the reverse is working

```
sed 's/,/\
/g' file
```

it replaces `,` with newline.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is not able to eat newlines in a simple way. `sed` works on a line-by-line basis, so it can only add newlines, not remove them. But you can effectively [do some sed gymnastics by storing two consecutive lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n). You may also want to have a look at `tr`, which is able to replace characters, for example:

```
tr '\n' , < file
```

Also, with many tools you can use `'\n'` to represent the line feed character (used for UNIX line breaks).

Like Stephane pointed, `tr` will replace *all* the line feeds (including the last one). You may prefer to use `paste`, which will join the lines using a specified delimitier:

```
paste -sd, file
```

Comment: `tr '\n' ,` will transliterate _every_ newline character including the last one. `paste -sd, file` is generally more appropriate (joins the lines with `,`) as you don't make assumptions on how lines are implemented under the scene. Also why concatenating a single file?

Comment: Yeah, right, I totally forgot that `paste` could be used here, and it does indeed solve the problem with the last newline (one hack is adding `;echo`, but that's more of a dirty hack and still leaves a last `,`); as for concatenating a single file, you can see that in the *question* the OP does mention a single file as an argument to `sed`...

Comment: njsg, I think Stephane was suggesting to not use `cat` when there is no actual concatenation to be done, ie. implying to use `<file tr '\n' ,` or  `tr '\n' , <file` instead, thereby avoiding an unnecessary process.

Comment: Peter.O, right I've edited this to include Stephane's suggestions and notes.